# Android App to modify function of other applications

Tags: android

I am just getting back into Android programming after a while and I know that separate Android applications are allowed to communicate with each other in some capacity, but is it possible for one to build a proprietary application that can modify the features of an already existing application?

I don't mean applications like those 3rd Instagram applications (which were most likely built using their api ). I mean is it possible to create an application that would for example run in the background and possibly add features on already existing applications?

For example making an extension application for that runs in the background when you use the Twitter application that could potentially add features, or disable existing features?

(Sorry if this is not directly relevant I did not know where else to post this question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In android apps are sandboxed.

It will be a major security issue if one app could influence the operation of other apps.

What can be done is letting apps interact with each other and exchange information, there are couple of ways to do this that relay on android Inter process communication, Android Binder Content providers and Intents.

What you can do is to draw on other apps. this will allow you to add some functionality without really changing anything in the background app
There are some apps that use this technique. LastPass is a good example.
See [this article](https://medium.com/@rotxed/drawing-over-other-apps-marshmallow-edition-987eff9f99a9) for more information

Comment: Yes thats what I was looking for "Drawing over other applications" thank you! Is there something similar with iOS applications? (Pardon my ignorance never had an iPhone)

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible on iOS

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!